# What other media types are available in twitter4j except for 'photo'

Tags: twitter4j

I'm trying to datamine the twitter stream using Twitter4J library, on receiving the `twitter4j.Status` I iterate the MediaEntitie's and try to find entities other than the 'photo' specified in the type attribute. Is it possible at all? When I navigate to '`getType`' method on `MediaEntity` class I can see the doc comment sayin: 'Returns the media type ("photo").'. If it only returns 'photo' whats the purpose of this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In last version in twitter4j:

> Returns the media type ("photo", "video", "animated_gif").